# Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-server-2012

I am trying to write a program that will connect to a remote server and display some status of a service. The service is also written by us (my company).

To do that I wrote a console app and the code is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Password = "mypassword";
        options.Username = "Administrator";
        options.Impersonation =
            System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

        ManagementScope scope =
            new ManagementScope(
            "\\\\ip_of_the_server\\root\\cimv2", options);
        scope.Connect();

        ServiceController svc = new ServiceController("My_Service_Name", "ip_of_the_server");

        var status = svc.Status.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(svc.DisplayName + " : " status);

    }
```

But I can not make it work. The error i get is:

```
Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'ip_of_the_server'. This operation might require other privileges.
```

inner exception: "Access Denied".

stack trace:

```
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetDataBaseHandleWithAccess(String     machineName, Int32 serviceControlManaqerAccess)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetDataBaseHandleWithConnectAccess()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GenerateNames()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.get_ServiceName()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GenerateStatus()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.get_Status()
   at ServiceConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Kandroid\Documents\Visual Studio     2013\Projects\ServiceConsole\ServiceConsole\Program.cs:line 33
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity,   String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Any idea how to solve it??

Comment: Use an account with the correct permissions?

Comment: :) yes offcourse. BUt I am using 'Administrator'. and also what kind of permission I need?

Comment: You setup an managementscope but I don't see that one go anywhere in your ServiceController, right?

Comment: ok. u mean i do have to use the scope with servicecontroller somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already did setup an managementscope, just use WQL to query the WMI provider for the correct WMI Object, in this case [WIN32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx), something like this:

```
var svc = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    scope,
    new ObjectQuery("Select Status,State from Win32_Service  where Name='My_Service_Name'"))
        .Get()
        .GetEnumerator();

    if (svc.MoveNext())
    {
          var status = svc.Current["Status"].ToString();
          var state = svc.Current["State"].ToString();
          Console.WriteLine("service status {0}", status);
          // if not running, StartService
          if (!String.Equals(state, "running",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) {
               ( (ManagementObject) svc.Current ).InvokeMethod("StartService", new object[] {});
          }
    }
    else 
    {
           Console.WriteLine("service not found");
    }
```

The [ManagementObjectSearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx)  is responsible for retrieving a collection of WMI managedobjects. An [ObjectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.objectquery(v=vs.110).aspx) will return instances of classes from the scope. We can execute basic sql select statements to select and project resultsets.

The iterator returns an [ManagementObjectBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.item(v=vs.110).aspx) that has as `Item` accessor to retrieve properties from the returned instance.

Comment: Thanks...Your code works. But in this way how would I start and stop the service?

Comment: I added the code to Invoke the StartService operation

Comment: Thanks a lot..Now i can take it from here...:)